# How to change the font of the lettrine?

Tags: fonts, lettrine

I would like to change the font of the letrrine

```
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\fontfamily{the_name}}

\lettrine[lines=3, lhang=0.33, loversize=0.25]{B}{ecause}
```

using this font: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/script

which is installed in

```
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/calligra-type1/callig15.pfb
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/afm/public/calligra-type1/callig15.afm
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/calligra/callig15.mf
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/calligra/callig15.tfm
```

However, I do not know how to specify correctly its name. I tried

```
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\fontfamily{callig15}}
```

But it gives

```
Font Shape 'T1/callig15/m/n' undefined(font)
```

Thanks for your help!

nbi

Comment: You have to do `\usepackage{calligra}`; then the family name is `calligra`, not `callig15`; instead of `\fontfamily{calligra}` you can simply say `\calligra`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to load `calligra` that defines the font; the family name will be `calligra`, but you can select it by `\calligra`. The font is very slanted, so `findent` should be specified.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{calligra}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\calligra}

\begin{document}

\lettrine[lines=3, lhang=0.33, loversize=0.25, findent=1.5em]{B}{ecause}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. In general, how do you find the name of the font package you want to load?

Comment: @nbi Experience, mostly.