# lettrine with euler font

Tags: fonts, lettrine, euler

I added drop caps to my document using the `lettrine` package, but would like to change their font to `eurb10`, because my `koma` rebuild of the `classicthesis` style uses `euler` chapter numbers, but cannot get it to work.

As sanity check, I tried to [set the font to calligra](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195166/how-to-change-the-font-of-the-lettrine), which works (please ignore the ugly alignment of the slanted drop cap), but needs to import the `calligra` package. In a desperate wild-guessing attempt, I've tried importing the `eulervm` package, guessing that it might contain the font, but this just "breaks" my math fonts (expected).

I'm suprised that I can define the chapternumber font [following the solution here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336002/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-the-chapter-numbers/336006#336006) without loading any font package ...

What am I missing? Also, any solution should not break the palatino math font ...

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, numbers=noenddot, twoside,openright, parskip=half]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[dvipsnames, table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}

\usepackage{lettrine}
%\usepackage{eulervm} % doesn't help and math is not nice 
%\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\eurb10} % <====== doesn't work
%\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\pplr9d} % <====== doesn't work

\usepackage{calligra}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\calligra} % <====== works
\newcommand{\collettr}[3][lines=3]{\lettrine[#1]{\textcolor{halfgray}{#2}}{#3}}

\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo} % nice bookish font Palatino with real small caps and old style figures
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}  % koma with roman headings

\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{textcase} % needed to make entries from the personal info upper/lower case
\microtypesetup{expansion=false}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedallcaps}[1]{\textls[160]{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}}%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{\textls[80]{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}%

% chapter format
\newcommand\titlerule[1][1pt]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
    \@hangfrom{#2}{#3}%
    \color{halfgray}\par\nobreak\titlerule%
}
\makeatother
\DeclareFixedFont{\chapterNumber}{U}{eur}{b}{n}{60}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
    \rlap{\makebox[\linewidth][r]{} 
    \color{halfgray}\enskip\chapterNumber\thechapter\autodot}
}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\mdseries\scshape\lsstyle\Large}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chapter title}
    \collettr{F}{irst} sentence of the chapter followed by \lipsum[8]
    \begin{equation}
    \omega(x) = \omega_0 \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x}{x_0}\right)^2}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for

```
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\usefont{U}{eur}{b}{n}\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}
```

to access a font at in a specified encoding and style

Comment: `Undefined control sequence.
\LettrineFontHook ->\UseFont`??

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes who wrote that:-)